# Discriminate type by index of array in map

Tags: typescript

Is there a way in typescript to access elements using a map with the correct type? The following throws an error because the type from map is `number | string`

```
type Tuple = [number, number, string];

const y: Tuple = [1, 2, 'apple'];

y[0] // correctly typed as number
y[2] // correctly typed as string

y.map((el, i) => {

    if (i === y.length - 1) {
        el + 3
    } else {
        el + "pear"
    }
})
```

Comment: That's because nothing stops you from doing `i += window.someVar` or `i += 15` before the `if`. So the correct type of the `i`th element can only be determined at runtime, which TypeScript doesn't do.

Comment: That's true, I hadn't considered that. It still fails with `type Tuple = Readonly<[number, number, string]>` though

Comment: What is `x` in `x.length - 1`? You mean `y.length - 1`?

Comment: Yes, should be y there, have corrected

Answer (score 0):

if you sure your tuple only has two string and number types, you can use `typeof` like this:

```
y.map((el, i) => {
    if (typeof el === 'number'){
       el + 3
    } else {
        el + "pear"
    }
})
```

[PlaygorundLink](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgrmANtAvFA2gOzgWwEYQBOANFNvkaQM7CECWmA5gLoDcAUOwMYD2mNUEAC5YCZFDToAjKQBMpAOQBDMEggK2ndiAB0OFQAoDERKToBKCQD4oAb3ZRHUOgDMoB0JB5uTElGgVyAkIFc3snCN8AaigAZgcnAF8oEypocIinaKgAIkglQhyEx0T2RPMgA)

Comment: This only works if the array length can be hardcoded, which it could be in this very simple case but I need a solution that works where `y` could be a tuple of any types/length including `[...number[], string]`

Comment: @Tom OK another way is using `typeof`. Check it updated answer

Comment: just an example there, could be elements of any type with a spread and a single last element